# Define matrix inline: LibreOffice Calc vs OpenOffice Calc

Tags: matrix, libreoffice-calc

I've read how to create a matrix in LibreOffice using [the inline definition](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions#Using_Inline_Array_Constants_in_Formulas).

I've tried in OpenOffice 4.1.1 and it works well.

```
={1;2;3|4;5;6|7;8;9}
```

creates:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Using the same formula in LibreOffice 4.4.2.2 renders:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Is it a known bug in LibreOffice Calc or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link in your question:

> The column separator (separating elements in one row) and the row separator are language and locale dependent. But in this help content, the ';' semicolon and '|' pipe symbol are used to indicate the column and row separators, respectively. For example, in the English locale, the ',' comma is used as the column separator, while the ';' semicolon is used as the row separator.

On my system, this works for LibreOffice: `={1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9}`.

However,
 Apache OpenOffice uses this: `={1;2;3|4;5;6|7;8;9}`.  From the [AOO docs](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc/Features/array_constants_in_formulas):

> Contrary to Excel, the separators are not UI-version and/or locale dependent.

Comment: And we have to go to Tools > Options > LibreOffice Calc to check what are the locale in use on our version. Thanks.